# How to prevent page counts by search indexers

Tags: web-crawlers, statistics, visitors

On a page I manage I store information about the most read pages and last read pages in the database.

How can I manage to prevent taking into account accesses from search indexers?

Note that I still want the pages to be indexed. But the page read counts should only be updated for human reads and not by robots. I tried to filter out some user-agents but that approach does not seem to be ideal.

Comment: You can block them with a [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard), but those pages won't be indexed as a result. If you're asking in regards to something else, please clarify your question.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Can you tell us what analytics or statistics application you're using, or did you code the page tracking yourself?

Comment: I believe user-agent approach is the only way to achieve this. You can find the list of user-agents on http://www.user-agents.org/ or http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

Answer (score 1):

Use your chosen language to detect the user agent. Most legitimate search engine crawlers have their own user agent to identify it as a crawler. Then you can simply ignore those user agents.